# Freeze up or Froze up

Tags: tense, phrasal-verbs

Which one is correct sentence?

1. I'd had the bladder and drinking  hose "freeze up" in races before.
2. I'd had the bladder and drinking hose "froze up" in races before.

Comment: I edited out your rant about EL&U. If you disagree with their decision, the correct place to bring it up is in the [EL&U Meta site](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/), not here.

Answer (score 2):

Only sentence 1 is correct.

Generally speaking, there can only be one *conjugated verb* per subject in a clause. "I" is the only subject, and its conjugated verb is "had".

In your sentence 2, the verb form "froze" is the simple past -- a conjugated verb form -- but it has no subject, so it cannot be correct.

"freeze up", however, is the *base form* of the verb -- a non-conjugated form -- so it's acceptable.

The structure *[ "have" + object + base form verb ]* roughly has the meaning: "The object verbed, and it was bad for me". In your example, it means, "The bladder and drinking hose froze up, and it was bad for me."

Comment: What about Bladder and Hose?. Can't they be subjects?

Comment: @Rocky "bladder and hose" are the direct object of "had". A noun cannot be both a subject and an object in the same clause. They certainly do the action of "freeze up", but grammatically they cannot act as both subject and object.

Comment: Oh yes thanks for correcting me.