# Conjugated verbs in a clause

Tags: verbs, conjugations

Somebody mentioned me on stackexchange(link is provided in the end) that we can have only one conjugated verb per subject in a clause. I typed these sentences in Gmail just to check gmail AI  and it shows these results.

1. I had known soldiers die. (correct)
2. I had known soldiers died.(correct)
3. I had seen soldiers die.(correct)
4. I had seen soldiers died.(error)

Why with 'had known' both 'die' and 'died' are okay?

[Freeze up or Froze up](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/335942/freeze-up-or-froze-up/335947?noredirect=1#comment638882_335947)

Comment: …and your question is…

Comment: If your question is something like "then why is either *die* or *died* correct", have you considered that "I had known" and "soldiers die/died" are separate clauses?  Think of it as "I had known **that**..."

Comment: (2) doesn't look correct to me unless, as Stangdon suggests, you insert _that_.

Comment: The most salient interpretation of your examples is that only 1. and 3 are correct. "Know" is a catenative verb and "(to) die" is its catenative complement.

Answer (score 1):

The grammar of "know" is different from the grammar of "see", and the form of "die" in 1 and 3 is not the same.

"Know" can take any *declarative* clause (with optional "that") as a complement:

> I know (that) soldiers die(d).

This means I know the fact that soldiers die(d).

"Die" can be simple present or simple past or any other tense because any clause works after "know".

"See", however, takes a complement in the form *[ object + base form ]*:

> I saw [him die].

To really convince ourselves that "die" is base form and not present simple, let's use the verb "be":

> I saw [him **be** killed].

4. is an error because "died" is not base form.